# How to convert an object to string in Emacs Lisp, quoting symbols so it can be read back?

Tags: elisp, read-eval-print-loop

I'd like to use a function similar to `prin1-to-string`, but which retains quotes for symbols and writes all objects in a way that can be sent back to `eval`. If I use `prin1-to-string`, it removes the quotes from symbols:

```
ELISP> (prin1-to-string 'a)
"a"
ELISP> (prin1-to-string '(2 a))
"(2 a)"
```

But the string "a" is not the form I passed to `prin1-to-string`. The function I want would work as this:

```
ELISP> (great-printing-function 'a)
"'a"
ELISP> (great-printing-function '(2 a))
"(2 'a)"
```

This is for handling history in a toy REPL I've been working on (different from IELM -- one that would be usable in a terminal) -- that's why I mentioned it will be sent back to eval.
Maybe there is some variable that would cause `prin1-to-string` to not unquote symbols? Or some other function? Otherwise, I'd probably need to code a tree-walker...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the use-case.  I mean, `(equal '(2 a) (read "(2 a)"))`  is `t`, for instance.  Quoting simply tells `eval` to return the object which `read` produced.  If you want to keep a history of the original text/code entered by the user, just remember that yourself at the time they enter it?

Comment: @phils `(eval (read "(2 a)"))` will fail, because it tries to eval 2 as a function... The original input by the user had a quote, which was lost when it went throguh `prin1-to-string`...

Comment: Ok, there seems to not be one. But I realize I can insert a single quote in the string, before sendind it to `read`...

Comment: But it sounds like you want to sending the thing you're quoting directly to `eval`?  Again, `eval`ing a `quote`d value just gives you that value.  `(eval (quote (read "FOO")))` is no different to `(read "FOO")`.

Comment: If the user enters `'(2 a)` then you should be remembering that input string `"'(2 a)"` yourself.  It sounds like you're trying to *recreate* the original code from the `eval`'d result, rather than just remembering it in the first place.

Comment: Yes - that's the problem. I read from the string it and store the object in history; I'm not keeping the string itself. You're right, it would be better to remember the string (there was a reason to store the read object  and not the string, but I can fix that).

Comment: Remembering that original string is the correct approach IMO; but I'll add that if you were storing *only* the `read` result, then you wouldn't have been losing the quote, as `(read "'(2 a)")` produces `(quote (2 a))`.  You wouldn't get just `(2 a)` unless you `eval`'d it -- and hoping to get the original code back after an `eval` is like hoping to come up with `(+ 2 3)` if all you had to start with was `5`.  Of course, if the user typed `'...` then you don't really want `(quote ...)` in the interactive history, which is one of the reasons to give them their original input verbatim.

Comment: Wait - there's one more thing. The REPL remember not only the inputs, but the outputs. I forgot I was talking about the outputs here, so there is no original string...

Comment: Oh, that's unusual.  I don't think you should *do* anything to those output history values, though.  I just wouldn't recommend interspersing the input and output histories in a single list / UI.  Keep them separate, and enable the user to *either* cycle through their input history (in which case they will expect to see the strings they originally wrote), *or* through the output history (in which case they won't expect to necessarily be able to submit the value directly as new input).

Comment: IOW if, as a user, I enter `(list 2 'a)` as input and receive the expected `(2 a)` as output, and I then pull that `(2 a)` back from the output history *and submit it verbatim as new input, without editing* then the fact that I wind up with an error will be of no surprise whatsoever.  I don't think it would make sense for the REPL to be attempting to manipulate the output into anything other than what it was originally.

Comment: I was looking for something similar to OP and found `macroexp-quote` to be useful. For example: `(macroexp-quote '(2 a))` returns `'(2 a)`. Works with a variable instead of literal input. I found it by looking at Customize package source code to see how they save user options.